# css moving div below text results

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am trying to move a div below auto complete search results. But i am unable to push the div below autocomplete results after user starts typing. I am trying to implement searchbox similar to www.microsoft.com. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my [Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/whhT7/)

```
<input name="query" id="pageSearchField" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">

    var availableTags = [
        "Details",
        "Project ",
        "Release ",
        "Property ",
        "Application",
        "Last Modified By",
        "Last Modified Date",
        "Tagged by"            
    ];
    $("#pageSearchField").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });



$("#pageSearchField").click(function () {
        $('#bottom-div').show("slow");
    });
    $('#pageMainRegion').click(function () {
        $('#bottom-div').hide("slow");
    });
    $('#bottom-div>div').css("background-color", "white");

    var firstFilterText = "Search Data Centers";
    var secondFilterText = "Search Projects";
    var thirdFilterText = "Search Orders";
    $("#pageSearchField").after("" +
        "<div  id=" + "bottom-div" + "><div>" + firstFilterText + "</div>" +
        "<div>" + secondFilterText + "</div>" +
        "<div>" + thirdFilterText + "</div></div>");

    $('#bottom-div>div').click(function () {
        $('#bottom-div>div').css("background-color", "white");
        $('#bottom-div>div').css("color", "black");
        $(this).css("background-color", "gray");
        $(this).css("color", "white");
    });


#bottom-div {
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 290px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    border-top-color: #000;
}

    #bottom-div > div {
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your jQuery like this:

```
$(".ui-autocomplete").after("" +
        "<div  id=" + "bottom-div" + "><div>" + firstFilterText + "</div>" +
        "<div>" + secondFilterText + "</div>" +
        "<div>" + thirdFilterText + "</div></div>");
```

remove `position:absolute` from your `bottom-div` and add this class to your CSS:

```
.ui-autocomplete{
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FS6Nv/)

with some style you can create what you want.

Comment: This looks great solution, but somehow its not working on my machine. I am trying to verify if there is some dependency breaking my work. Please give me some time to mark the answer.

Comment: @Usham look at new DEMO

Comment: This looks great solution, but somehow its not working on my machine. I am trying to verify if there is some dependency breaking my work. Please give me some time to mark the answer. My bottom div is moving down of the page when i click inside search box. I see this code with developer tool <div id="bottom-div" style="display: block;"><div>Search Data Centers</div><div>Search Projects</div><div>Search Orders</div></div>. Can we remove  style="display: block;" from code? I think that is moving my div down of the page.

Comment: its 100% same code as in the above fiddle. Let me trace the issue. I think its some dependency issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since Ui-Autocomplete has position:absolute, it will not affect page layout in the normal way and it will not push elements below it.

One approach is to [extend the ui autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderMenu) to render with your div [at the bottom of the autocomplete (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/HnLL8/)

```
 $.widget( "custom.autocompletePlus", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var original = this._super(ul, items);

        $(ul).append(
            "<p>Your Html goes here</p>"
        );
   }
 });


 $("#pageSearchField").autocompletePlus({
        source: availableTags,
    });
```

Comment: updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HnLL8/ added a line between the normal elements and the added elements